# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my assembly code?

Tags: assembly, armv8

My code is trying to find the word 'hello' in a given string, and return 'Found' if it is there, and 'Not found' if not.

When I debug it using `gdb`, I get a segmentation fault when it branches back to search after the first iteration.

Here is my code.

```
.data

input:  .asciz "hello world"
f:      .asciz "Found!"
nf:     .asciz "Not found!"
find:   .asciz "hello"

.text
.global main
main:
    adr x19, input
    mov x22, #0
    adr x21, find
    mov x23, #0

search:
    ldrb w21, [x21, x23, lsl #0]
    ldrb w19, [x19, x22, lsl #0]    
    cmp w19, #0         
    beq not             
    
    cmp w21, #0     
    beq found           

    cmp w21, w19            
    bne cont            

    add x22, x22, #1
    add x23, x23, #1

    b search


cont:
    add x22, x22, #1        
    mov x23, #0         

    b search

found:
    adr x20, f
    mov x0, x20
    bl printf

    b end

not:
    adr x20, nf
    mov x0, x20
    bl printf

    b end

end:
    mov x0, #0
    ret
```

Comment: When you have a segmentation fault, it will be on one single instruction,, which is most likely a load or a store.  If you want help with it, post the entire error message and identify the instruction that faults, and the register contents at the time of the fault.  With that information, you might even figure it out yourself.  One or more register is going to have a bad value at the fault and you have to work backward in the dynamic instruction stream to find out why. As you embark on debugging, know your data and its addresses, so you know what good addresses look like.

Comment: What value does `mov x21, find` put into x21?  Is it actually the address of the string, or did it get truncated?  Also, `ldrb w21, [x21, x23, lsl #0]` overwrites the pointer with the byte you loaded.  So of course the next iteration will crash.  `w21` is the low 32 bits of `x21`.

Comment: [ARMv8 assembly, How to move value from w register to x register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65134390) isn't an exact duplicate since the question is different (although perhaps sharing the misconception that w and x registers are separate).  The answer explains why this crashes: w19 is the same register as x19.

Comment: @PeterCordes that was a typo; I meant to put `adr x21, find`. And I see now; for some reason I thought they were separate. I changed the ldrb to different registers and I no longer get the error, but now it seems like I get stuck in a permanent loop since my code doesn't seem to advance.

Comment: Are you debugging using single step?  That, along with observation of your variables (e.g. in registers) will reveal why it doesn't advance.